# Assigning name to IAM Role with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-iam

how can we set/assign name of any IAM role while creating an IAM role with `cloudformation`. Say i want to create an `IAM` role with name `NewRole`, using cloudformation script, but i cant find any parameter in resource declaration for IAM role, where we can define name of the IAM role to be created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply provide the `RoleName` [(AWS docs)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-rolename) attribute on your role declaration.

yaml:

`RoleLogicalId:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  Properties:
    RoleName: String
    [...]`

Note that the documentation contains warnings and notes the consequences of using this attribute.

p.s. @dsmsk80 *was* correct but this was changed.

Answer (score 1):

IAM role name is not possible to set from CloudFormation template. But you know how it is formatted when the stack and related role resource is created:

```
CFStackName-CFIAMRoleResourceName-RandomString
```

[CloudFormation AWS::IAM::Role resource documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html)

Comment: can't we define IAM role name by defining Role ARN parameter ?..